# Is there any way to get the current HTTP response code from PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the HTTP response code that will be sent from inside a PHP script, e.g., a script like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');

$code = imaginary-function(); // $code contains 404
```

I noticed the `http_response_code` function in the PHP docs, but that doesn't seem to be available in PHP 5.3.9.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php ?

Comment: @glavić - [headers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) might be more what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Jared Farrish: The problem is that headers_list() doesn't return the HTTP response code that's been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has apparently been added in PHP 5.4, but I have not verified this.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.4, `http_response_code()` will get or set the value.

Answer (score -2):

This `headers_list` might be what you are looking for

docs :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

> headers_list() will return a list of headers to be sent to the browser / client. To determine whether or not these headers have been sent yet, use headers_sent().

If the headers_list not doing what you need, here is another route (troublesome) :-

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-register-callback.php

Comment: Thanks, but the values returned by that don't seem to contain the response code.

Comment: Well, is an array, you can parse it simply using regexp or strpos

Comment: What I mean is that there isn't any value indicating the response code in that array. I tried setting the response code and then running headers_list.

Comment: `Headers will only be accessible and output when a SAPI that supports them is in use.`

Comment: The rest of the headers are output, though.