# In PHP < 5.4 is there any way to get a status response code you just set?

Tags: php, apache

I know in php 5.4 there is a new function `http_response_code()`, but in prior versions how would you get a response code you just set?

Similar to [Is there any way to get the current HTTP response code from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367877/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-current-http-response-code-from-php)

I have this need:

```
 //sometime earlier
 header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');


//sometime later, detect if error was set
$status = some_magic_way_to_find_status();
```

Does anyone have a way in php 5.3 or below to do this?

Comment: If you know you are sending a 404, why not just save it in a variable?  `$http_code = 404;`?

Comment: I suppose upgrading to 5.4 is out of the question?

Comment: @Rocket this is a possibility, but the 404 is being set somewhere deep in the framework when it throws an exception--I'd prefer not to modify the framework library code directly.  Basically, we have a custom 404 page and don't want to show some of the default navigation and social buttons if on the error page.

Comment: And you're sure the framework doesn't provide any hooks for 404 ? What is the framework's name? Note that the problem you are having is "how to hook into my framework in a 404 situation". Yet your question doesn't reflect this at all :P

Comment: @SDC yes, for then next few months, 5.4 is but a dream :)

Comment: @Esailija good point, I'll check if I can register a callback into a 404 hook.  If so, I might be able to use one of the suggestions below.

Comment: Well, if you can do that what is the point of using the suggestions since if the callback is called you know it's going to be a 404.

Comment: @Esailija The exact situation is I have a custom 404 error page that uses the same logo, navigation, etc... as the regular pages.  In the view (long past when 404 event fires and the callbacks tied to the hook are run) we want to wrap some portions of the common navigation not to show when used on a 404 page.  We don't want to create duplicate versions and are trying to avoid setting a $suppress-this-thing boolean.  I'm trying to provide a simple method to let the view files check `isThisAnErrorPage()`.

Comment: I still don't see why you would need to sniff the status code when you have the callback telling you. In the callback you could set a `$is_error_page` variable to `true` and have `isThisAnErrorPage()` return it. Basically if you can properly hook, there is no reason to sniff the status code anymore?

Comment: @Esailija That's what we'll end up doing, setting a $is_error property in a common object we use for some common application state.  You should turn your comment into an answer and I'd check it.

Comment: @Esailija actually to your earlier point, the solution is not for the question I orriginally asked, and I think someone else has already indicated not it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

You could wrap the `header()` function:

```
function my_status_header($setHeader=null) {
    static $theHeader=null;
    //if we already set it, then return what we set before (can't set it twice anyway)
    if($theHeader) {return $theHeader;}
    $theHeader = $setHeader;
    header('HTTP/1.1 '.$setHeader);
    return $setHeader;
}
```

Or, of course, you could always upgrade to PHP5.4.

Comment: The 404 is being set somewhere deep in the framework when it throws an exception--I'd prefer not to modify the framework library code directly to add this wrapper.

Comment: found another solution to my root problem, but apparently your answer is the correct one--it's not possible to do this directly.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** As @Esailija wrote:
Notice that you need to rewrite all your header calls to use this function for this to work

Found this code in the manual,
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261

```
<?php

    if (!function_exists('http_response_code')) {
        function http_response_code($code = NULL) {

            if ($code !== NULL) {

                switch ($code) {
                    case 100: $text = 'Continue'; break;
                    case 101: $text = 'Switching Protocols'; break;
                    case 200: $text = 'OK'; break;
                    case 201: $text = 'Created'; break;
                    case 202: $text = 'Accepted'; break;
                    case 203: $text = 'Non-Authoritative Information'; break;
                    case 204: $text = 'No Content'; break;
                    case 205: $text = 'Reset Content'; break;
                    case 206: $text = 'Partial Content'; break;
                    case 300: $text = 'Multiple Choices'; break;
                    case 301: $text = 'Moved Permanently'; break;
                    case 302: $text = 'Moved Temporarily'; break;
                    case 303: $text = 'See Other'; break;
                    case 304: $text = 'Not Modified'; break;
                    case 305: $text = 'Use Proxy'; break;
                    case 400: $text = 'Bad Request'; break;
                    case 401: $text = 'Unauthorized'; break;
                    case 402: $text = 'Payment Required'; break;
                    case 403: $text = 'Forbidden'; break;
                    case 404: $text = 'Not Found'; break;
                    case 405: $text = 'Method Not Allowed'; break;
                    case 406: $text = 'Not Acceptable'; break;
                    case 407: $text = 'Proxy Authentication Required'; break;
                    case 408: $text = 'Request Time-out'; break;
                    case 409: $text = 'Conflict'; break;
                    case 410: $text = 'Gone'; break;
                    case 411: $text = 'Length Required'; break;
                    case 412: $text = 'Precondition Failed'; break;
                    case 413: $text = 'Request Entity Too Large'; break;
                    case 414: $text = 'Request-URI Too Large'; break;
                    case 415: $text = 'Unsupported Media Type'; break;
                    case 500: $text = 'Internal Server Error'; break;
                    case 501: $text = 'Not Implemented'; break;
                    case 502: $text = 'Bad Gateway'; break;
                    case 503: $text = 'Service Unavailable'; break;
                    case 504: $text = 'Gateway Time-out'; break;
                    case 505: $text = 'HTTP Version not supported'; break;
                    default:
                        exit('Unknown http status code "' . htmlentities($code) . '"');
                    break;
                }

                $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');

                header($protocol . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $text);

                $GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = $code;

            } else {

                $code = (isset($GLOBALS['http_response_code']) ? $GLOBALS['http_response_code'] : 200);

            }

            return $code;

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Note that he needs to rewrite all his `header` calls to use this function for this to work

Comment: No doubt, it just should be noted when it's not immediately clear. I didn't mean to discredit or anything, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: No problem , added your note to the answer.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Similar to some other suggestions, The 404 is being set somewhere deep in the framework when it throws an exception--I'd prefer not to modify the framework library code directly to write this additional info to a global array.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Also, I've got a code base of over 100M using a couple different libraries that set status in a number of ways, not just with the header() function. Hunting down every setting of header-especially in 3rd party libraries isn't going to work for me.

Comment: Yes , you're right , hunting down every setting of header can be a nightmare.

Comment: As an alternative, we've created a library (available to be used with Composer) to smooth out the differences in solving this between our projects: https://github.com/mckay-software/httpstatus.php

Answer (score 1):

For set http code use with PHP 5.3 or prior (you can create a file called `http_response_code.php` and put this content):

```
/*Check if function is available (php5.3<)*/
if (false === function_exists('http_response_code')) {
    /* Fallback */

    function http_response_code($code = null)
    {
        static $currentStatus;

        if ($code === null) {
            if ($currentStatus !== null) {
                return $currentStatus;
            }

            $currentStatus = 200;

            if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === false &&
                preg_match('#/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(\d{3})\.html$#', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $match) > 0)
            {
                $currentStatus = (int) $match[1];
            }
        } elseif (is_int($code) && headers_sent() === false) {
            header('X-PHP-Response-Code: ' . $code, true, $code);
            $currentStatus = $code;
        }

        return $currentStatus;
    }
}
```

For use call:

```
<?php

require 'foo/bar/http_response_code.php';

$code = http_response_code();
http_response_code(403);

echo 'Initial HTTP code: ', $code, '<br>', PHP_EOL;
echo 'Current HTTP code: ', http_response_code(), '<br>', PHP_EOL;
```

This code returns:

> Initial HTTP code: 200
>   Current HTTP code: 403

---

This function check server error using URL reserved, for work use this configs:

**.htacces (Apache)**

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-404.html
```

**nginx**

```
error_page 404 /RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-404.html;
error_page 403 /RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html;

location ~ ^/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(403|404)\.html$ {
    rewrite ^/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(403|404)\.html$ /error.php$0 last;
}
```

**IIS**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="403" />
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="403" path="/error.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/error.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-501.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The `error.php` is a example, can change if needed. In your script page use (error.php):

```
<?php

require 'foo/bar/http_response_code.php';

echo 'Error page, status: ', http_response_code();
```

For load a "template":

```
<?php

require 'foo/bar/http_response_code.php';

include 'template/error/http_' . $code . '.php';
```